# is there are any easier way to write multiline JavaScript string

Tags: javascript

how to write a multiline string in JavaScript. I know

```
var txt = "line1"+
"line2"+
"line3";
```

works. but any better and quicker way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this

```
var txt = "line1 \
Line2 \
Line3";
```